# Removing duplicate values from an array of elements by invoking the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I want the following function, when invoked to return an array of elements without duplicates

```
const removeDuplicates = nums => {
 var result = Array.from(new Set(nums));
  console.log(result)   
}
removeDuplicates([1,1,2,2,3])
```

Basically, I want this function to work without `console.log` 
but with invocation of it, like so `removeDuplicates([1,1,2,2,3])` 
Please note that `return` is not working in this case as it stops the function from being invoked.

P.S. I have read a lot of answers related to my question, however they are not specifically answering my question; in particular, I want to invoke the `removeDuplicates` function with provided array of elements, like so: `removeDuplicates([1,1,2,2,3])` and I expect it to return the elements without duplicates.

Comment: Why is `return Array.from(new Set(nums))` not an option?

Comment: just return Array.from...

Comment: Yes, thanks, the repl on which I was trying code was not working, I guess because I have chosen to create JS/HTML/CSS repl instead of just Javascript

Comment: In that repl can log to console or do something in the dom with the results. The script is running, you just aren't doing anything with the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect it to return the elements

So add a `return`

```js
const removeDuplicates = nums => {
  return Array.from(new Set(nums));
}

const res = removeDuplicates([1, 1, 2, 2, 3])

console.log(res)
```

Or use an implicit return

```
const removeDuplicates = nums => Array.from(new Set(nums));
```

Comment: Yes, that is very logical/correct; however it is not working, I am trying it on repl, here is the link: https://repl.it/@umbur/FaintSlushyModel

Comment: I don't see you doing anything with res in the repl

Comment: The code that you've provided is in script.js of that repl; however it works fine on this repl, which was created by choosing only JS: https://repl.it/@umbur/HotSerpentineProcedurallanguage

Comment: Understand ... add this and run again `document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res)` and if you log to console the repl console will work

Comment: Does not work, but I guess it is not important, as the issue is solved now; thanks again!